# Alternatives to Live/GamerServices for XNA projects?

Tags: networking, xna

Using the GamerServices component for XNA to access Xbox/GfW Live for networking purposes requires developers and players each to have a US$100/year subscription to Microsoft's Creators Club. That's not much of an issue for Xbox360 XNA projects as you need the subscription anyway to be able to put your game on the 360.

But for PC games using XNA, requiring developers and players to put that much up each year is pretty crazy just for the access to a player's gamer card. Are there any solutions for XNA games that provide similar benefits to GamerServices? Or are developers pretty much restricted to building their own networking functionality if they don't want to subject their players (and themselves) to that $100/head hit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you could try [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3)

Comment: That link is now dead; library is here: http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

Answer (score 2):

Please note that games for windows live is now free: 
http://www.engadget.com/2008/07/22/games-for-windows-live-now-free/

Since using the Live APIs is your only option on xbox and zune, it makes it a pretty compelling option since your only issue was the cost on windows :-) Especially considering  the fact that once game studio 3.0 launches, you'll be able to sell your games on xbox live's new community games section

*Edit, upon further investigation, it turns out that the games for windows live stuff is kind of half-baked.  The gamerservices library doesn't seem to be included in the redistributable bits.  So unless you want to break the EULA, your player would have to install gamestudio.  That being said, I do still believe that it's free nonetheless, if not inconvenient.*

Comment: I have neither a Zune nor a 360 (although I'd love to have both, issues of cost put them out of reach). That right there restricts me to PC development anyway. And what about people who aren't interested in making their games fit on those platforms?

Comment: I know Windows for Games is free, but a Creators Club membership is still needed to make or play games that use it. That's the crux of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use sockets, obviously, and using sockets you can create a seperate, dedicated server app, which you can't do with Live (as far as I know). You could also try SteamWorks; I haven't heard of anyone trying that, however.